# How to access to the informations related to the facets of a convex hull in a dD triangulation?

Tags: cgal, triangulation, convex-hull

I am rewriting codes that were using the class CGAL::Convex_hull_d, that is now deprecated. My need is to compute dynamically the convex hull of a set of points, and next to access to a a point and the normal of each facet.

The way to traverse the facets of a convex hull obtained by a triangulation is perfectly clear in the documentation, the problem is next to access to the informations related to the facets.

For the three-dimensional case, I have used the class CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3. After inserting points in the triangulation (called T), it is possible to obtain the convex hull using the CGAL::Surface_mesh class and the function CGAL::convex_hull_3_to_face_graph. Next, we can use facet iterators to traverse the facets, and next vertex iterators to access to the vertices of a facet. There is also a direct access to the normal to a facet using the function CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::compute_face_normal. This is described by the following portion of code.

`Surface_mesh chull;`

`CGAL::convex_hull_3_to_face_graph(T,chull);`

`Surface_mesh::Face_range mesFaces = chull.faces();`

`Surface_mesh::Face_range::iterator debut,fin;`

`CGAL::Vertex_around_face_iterator<Surface_mesh> vbegin,vend;`

`debut = mesFaces.begin();`

`fin = mesFaces.end();`

`while(debut != fin)`
`{`

`Vector_3 p = CGAL::Polygon_mesh::compute_face_normal(*debut,chull);`

`std::cout << "Normal to the facet: (" << p[0] << "," << p[1] << "," << p[2] << ")" << std:endl;`

`boost::tie(vbegin,vend) = vertices_around_face(chull.halfedge(*debut),chull);`

`Point_3 po = chull.point(*vbegin);`

`std::cout << "One point of the facet: (" << po[0] << "," << po[1] << "," << po[2] << ")" << std:endl;`

`debut++;`

`}`

However, the classes CGAL::Delaunay_Triangulation_3 and CGAL::Surface_mesh class cannot be used to compute the convex hull of a set of points with 4 dimensions. I have therefore considered the (recommended) use of dD Triangulation (in particular, the class CGAL::Triangulation). To traverse the facets of the convex hull is not a problem as a two full examples are given in the documention. Below, the first one is given.

`{ int i=0;`

`typedef Triangulation::Full_cell_iterator Full_cell_iterator;`

`typedef Triangulation::Facet Facet;`

`for( Full_cell_iterator cit = t.full_cells_begin();cit != t.full_cells_end(); ++cit )`

`{`

`if( ! t.is_infinite(cit) )`

`continue;`

`Facet ft(cit, cit->index(t.infinite_vertex()));`

`++i;// |ft| is a facet of the convex hull`

`}`

`std::cout << "There are " << i << " facets on the convex hull."<< std::endl;`

`}`

Here, the Facet ft is created but not used, the facets are only counted. I have not found a way to access to any information related to the facet in the documentation. My need would be the same as for the three-dimensional case.

Comment: You can get the vertices from the full cell (ignoring the infinite vertex). I am afraid you'll have to compute the normal yourself.

Comment: Thanks! It just works! I can indeed access to the vertices from the full cell, and the normal can fortunately be deduced from these vertices.